# JavaScript failing and the cause is not clear

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a simple thing in my code. According the value of a dropdown, I need to set display none to other divs.
This first part of the code, is when I fill the page with the information from database.

```
<div class="row" id="boxNivelDesconto">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoNivelDesconto)
                <div class="right">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodigoNivelDesconto, ViewBag.ListaDescontos as SelectList, new { @class = "big" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoNivelDesconto)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="boxJustificativaDesconto">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoJustificativaDesconto)
                <div class="right">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodigoJustificativaDesconto, ViewBag.ListaJustificativas as SelectList, new { @class = "big" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoJustificativaDesconto)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="boxListaCategoria">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoria)
                <div class="right">
                    @if (Model.TipoCliente == (short)Karcher.Portal.Web.Models.TipoCliente.PessoaJuridica)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodigoCategoria, ViewBag.ListaCategorias as SelectList, new { @class = "big" })
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodigoCategoria, ViewBag.ListaCategorias as SelectList, new { @class = "big oculto" })
                        <input id="CodigoCategoria-textbox" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" style="vertical-align: top; width: 367px" value="@Model.Categoria.Descricao" />
                    }
                    @Html.Hidden("CategoriaTrue", Model.CodigoCategoria)
                    <a class="item small text" id="ajuda" style="cursor: pointer" title="Selecione para visualizar a ajuda.">
                        <img alt="Ajuda?"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/theme/gfx/icons/small/help.png")" /><span>Ajuda</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="contOutros" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h2>
                                    Documentos necessários para anexo</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Segue abaixo os documentos necessários para anexar na proposta:</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Contrato Social ou Requerimento de Empresário <i>(opcional)</i></li>
                                    <li>Cartão CNPJ</li>
                                    <li>Sintegra (caso cliente possua I.E.)</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contRevenda" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h2>
                                    Documentos necessários para anexo</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Segue abaixo os documentos necessários para anexar na proposta:</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Contrato Social ou Requerimento de Empresário <i>(opcional)</i></li>
                                    <li>Cartão CNPJ</li>
                                    <li>Sintegra (caso cliente possua I.E.)</li>
                                    <li>Fotos fachada, balcão, estoque e oficina</li>
                                    <li>Carta de Autorização de débito em conta corrente </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contConsumidor" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h2>
                                    Documentos necessários para anexo</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Segue abaixo os documentos necessários para anexar na proposta:</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Contrato Social ou Requerimento De Empresário <i>(opcional)</i></li>
                                    <li>Descrição Do Material a ser negociado mais o Valor do Pedido </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><b>OBS.:</b> Ao negociar equipamentos(a partir da BD530)</li>
                                    <li>Enviar preenchido Contrato de Alienação</li>
                                    <li>Para locação enviar preemchido Contrato de Locação.</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoCategoria)
                </div>
            </div>
```

So, I have a simple verification about the fields values, and according this, some divs need to display none, as I said before.

```
if (($("#CodigoNivelDesconto").val() == '') && ($("#CodigoJustificativaDesconto").val() == '') && ($("#CodigoCategoria").val() == '12')) {
            $("#boxNivelDesconto").attr("style", "display:none;");
            $("#boxJustificativaDesconto").attr("style", "display:none;");
        }
```

But, when I run the page in Firefox for example, return to me an error message from javascript displaying "a.ownerDocument is null". Or in Chrome, the error message is "cannot read property 'tagname' of null".

Do anybody knows what is happening? Have any suggestion to solve it? It's making me crazy. I already tried a lot of workaround to solve it, but no success.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line number does it break? Is it possible for you to share your webpage? Or an isolated code showing problem using jsFiddle?

Comment: The error messages don't appear to be related to the code you've posted. There should be a reference to your source code in the message, and probably a stack trace.

Comment: Open the Developer Toolbar in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i). Then go to console, you'll see the error and a linenumber, along with a stack trace. Post actual html and the js code on that faulty line number.

Comment: Guys, when I try to see on browser debug the specific error, nothing appears to me. But, when I debug the javascript, the first stop is in code of jquery.dimensions.js, line 383. // Mozilla does not add the border for a parent that has overflow set to anything but visible
      if (mo && parent != elem && $.css(parent, 'overflow') != 'visible') {
       x += num(parent, 'borderLeftWidth');
       y += num(parent, 'borderTopWidth');
      }. It finishes in line 364 of costum.js, in catch, showing the error. I don't know if it helps you.

Comment: ...from my comment above, the exception is in this code: $(function () {
        try {
            $('.dataTables_length input, select:not(.multiple)').not("select.oculto").selectmenu({
                style: 'dropdown',
                transferClasses: true,
                width: null//,
//                change: function () {
//                  $(".valid").validate().element(this);
//                 }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }

    });

Comment: @AlisonVieira I think if you can share your rendered webpage, that would really help in figuring out the solution.

Comment: If everything else fails to help, backup the changes, rollback to the latest working version, add back code bit by bit. Once it blows up, you have pinpointed the cause. (On a side note, the error doesn't actually seem to be related to the code you provided, but seem more to be linked to some included js external).

Comment: Actually, the problem is in javascript code that posted in my ask, because when I take off this part from my source code, the page opens without problems. But why? This is the thing that I can't understand.

Comment: Guys, I've found the problem =D. I just changed the position of jquery code that I posted in my ask. I placed the code inside a $(window).load(function(){}), because inside $(document).ready(function(){}) it doesn't work. I think the jquery code was trying to check something that was not filled, I don't know why, because when I tried to check if the dropdown was filled, returned to me that it was. So, if someone can explain what happened, my happiness will be full!! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your selectors are returning what you expect?

Before the rest of your processing code, try checking you have something returned by your selectors, i.e.

```
if ($("#CodigoNivelDesconto").length > 0) { alert ('found it!'); }
```

I'm not familiar with MVC, but from what you've posted so far, it might be that you need to add @id to your helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodigoNivelDesconto, ViewBag.ListaDescontos as SelectList, new { @id="CodigoNivelDesconto", @class = "big" })
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but your comments didn't help me to find a solution. And about the id of the field, in fact when the dropdown is created by @Html, the id of the field will be the name of model field, in this case CodigoNivelDesconto.

Comment: I thought that with the id, it was likely to be the case it defaulted to name of the model field, but wasn't entirely sure.  Are you able to get a breakpoint on the line checking the selectors?  Perhaps even throw a 'debugger;' statement in just before your JS code to make sure you get that far?